How to use kustomize to set image version using version in package.json?
I'm having a devil of a time figuring out how to pull the version out of package.json and use it to set a tag on my image name in a deployment using kustomize.
I can easily pull the version from package.json using...
jq -r .version ../../api/package.json

... and I can figure out how to change my patch files via CI/CD to accomplish this - just replace tokens in my patch file with the value from the above script.
I'm running skaffold locally, however, and I need to be able to easily run kustomize against the base, and have it pull the version from package.json. I really don't want to add some other crazy layer of functionality on top if I can avoid it.
Is there a way to grab the version from package.json (like using jq above) and jam that version as a tag onto my image using kustomize?
